# How to stay logged in after the browser is closed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a chat application and I don't know how I retain a user session when the browser is closed.

When the user logs in for the first time, the browser should remember the users' credentials (I am using local storage). But how do I retain the user credentials?

Comment: What do you mean by "retain the page"? Also, you should look into `sessions` and `cookies` if you want people to stay logged in upon next visit.

Answer (score 3):

You really should use cookies for example.

With javascript you can set them via

```
document.cookie = "username=" + username;
```

for example.
(It is more secure to not directly store the username in the cookie, for various security reasons, tho.)

Check this out from W3Schools: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 3):

You should indeed use cookies like Tim says, but don't just save the username in the cookie. Instead, set a randomly generated token and save that in a database. When you load the site, you get the token and verify with your server who is logged in and whether the token is valid.

While you're at it, also link the token to IP address and user agent, this makes it more secure.

Comment: Agree, it's a better idea to store it like that.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer then. That makes it clear for everyone that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

the alternative to cookies is that  you could write the session inside the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser and initialize the application with the data from the local storage and check if they are still valid.